# Does content script have access to newtab page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

### Updated

Thanks @kofifus for the info, Chrome as of 61 [explicitly forbids](https://codereview.chromium.org/2978953002/) content scripts on its default new tab page

### Previous

Say I have the following sample extension, it will output `test` in console.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

content.js

```
console.log('test');
```

Will above extension work well in `chrome://newtab` page?

Some helpful info:

1. I know by default chrome extension can't access to `chrome://` pages, and we could change this behavior through `chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls`
2. `chrome://newtab` in fact is a url like `https://www.google.co.jp/_/chrome/newtab?espv=2&ie=UTF-8`, so it shouldn't be blocked by above restriction.
3. There are many mouse gestures extension available, like [crxMouse](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/crxmouse-chrome-gestures/jlgkpaicikihijadgifklkbpdajbkhjo?hl=en-US), they work well on `chrome://newtab` page
4. There are also some voices saying it's not allowed to inject content scripts in `chrome://newtab`, for example, @Xan's comments below [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36148196/chrome-extension-modify-newtab-page-body/36152749#36152749)
   [image]
   and [this author's case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947915/run-a-specified-function-when-the-user-opens-a-new-tab-in-chromium)
   [image]

So it looks weird as its different behavior across different devices( or settings?). Is there any official statements about whether content scripts can run in `chrome://newtab` pages? Or is there a setting we could change this behavior?

Comment: @wOxxOm, See #4, there are also some voices saying it's not allowed to inject content scripts into `chrome://newtab`

Comment: Note that in case of my comment #4, I really don't know. It was my educated guess.

Comment: @Xan, in fact I heard many voices about the inconsistent behavior for content scripts in new tab page. For my own experience, most time it works well in new tab page however I do ever meet the case that it doesn't work.

Comment: @wOxxOm, the question is, content scripts behavior in newtab is inconsistent. Some people find it not work while the others find it work well, they both simply declare matches as `<all_urls>` and without doing any other things. I want to know the reason causing that and if there is a setting we can change this behavior.

Comment: @wOxxOm, but there are also some people find it not work (see the examples in the post), even though they have declared `<all_urls>`

Comment: @wOxxOm: I am that third party. I have installed two extensions (AdBlock and pdf.js), but neither should do anything to the “New Tab” page. I installed Chromium from an Arch Linux package. Maybe I should try installing it directly from http://chromium.org/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Chrome as of 61 [explicitly forbids](https://codereview.chromium.org/2978953002/) content scripts on its default new tab page

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

> **Q: Is there any official statements about whether content scripts can run in chrome://newtab pages?**

A: Not really, but [Google's documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) states that:

> Host permissions and content script matching are based on a set of URLs defined by match patterns. A match pattern is essentially a URL that begins with a permitted scheme (http, https, file, or ftp, and that can contain '*' characters. The special pattern  matches any URL that starts with a permitted scheme.

**`chrome://newtab` only redirects the user to whatever url is set as the new tab page.**  Usually it will redirect the user to `https://<your local google domain>/_/chrome/newtab`(a permitted match pattern).  But if another extension sets the new tab page to `customNewTab.html`, then `chrome://newtab` will redirect the user to `chrome-extension://chrome-id/customNewTab.html`, and any other extension's content scripts will not be able to run on the new tab.

[This SA question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287333/what-is-the-url-of-the-google-chrome-new-tab-page-and-how-to-exclude-it-from-man) also confirms this.  If you try adding `"exclude_matches": ["*://*/_/chrome/newtab*"],` to your manifest, the content script will stop working on the new tab page.

> **Q: Is there a setting that could change this behavior?**

None beside an override page set by another extension. (Note that themes only change the appearance of the new tab, and won't override the new tab url)

> **Q: Will above extension work well in chrome://newtab page?**

A: yes, unless that tab was overriden by another extension.

I have a 30,000 user extension called Screen Shader on the extension store with a huge variety of different chrome versions and a few different browsers, and so far no one has complained about it not working on the new tab page, when they complain a lot about other things.

I'm not too sure why other people think it shouldn't work on the new tab page, but hopefully this answered all the questions you were having.

**On a sidenote: Keypress problems with the new tab page**

On his blogpost at http://www.toptip.ca/2010/01/google-chrome-content-script.html the developer of ["Boss Key and Button"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/boss-key-and-button/oodmocecapemhoekoombagkkbocnddjb) complains about issues with running a content script in the new tab page.  His extension minimizes all chrome windows and opens the one you are currently on in a new tab whenever you press <kbd>F9</kbd>.  He thought the content script didn't work on the new tab page because whenever he used his shortcut in the new tab page, nothing happened.  He failed to realize that the reason it wasn't working on the new tab page was because chrome redirects any keypresses to the browser bar so his content script could not capture the keypress.

Try using his extension and pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> on a random page. All chrome windows will be minimized.  go back to that random page, and click in the address bar and try pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>.  This time nothing will happen.

Comment: Does a theme count as an extension?

Comment: @pyon A theme only changes the background image and some of the styling in the page, so it doesn't override the default new tab url.

Comment: My new tab page seems to redirect me to `chrome-search://local-ntp/local-ntp.html` and not a google domain and I am unable to inject a content script here. Is there any way to inject a content script here? I already specified <all_urls> in my manifest's permissions